# Haml shows source code in browser

Tags: html, windows, haml

I can't find a solution on this. I want to let my Haml code work in the exact same way as HTML in Atom. I changed the name to test.html.haml and installed haml itself in CMD.

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple issues with the problem you described.
First off here is the official Tutorial on how to convert to haml:
[HAML Tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html)

As you successfully installed haml you can see on the [reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#using_haml):

> To run Haml from the command line, just use `haml input.haml output.html`

Which could be helpful, as you said, that you're using the command line.

Otherwhise more information, like the version you are using, as well as potential error-messages or the code you are using would be great to see.

Comment: I already followed the instructions on both links several times. I got confused with the 'haml input.haml output.html" And do not really know what to do with it.

I am using Haml 5.0.4 and the code

%strong{:class => "code", :id => "message"} Hello, World!

Comment: Alright the code as you wrote it looks alright.
Is there any error coming up as you try to run the code ?

Comment: I can't find any error in the console. The browser just shows the code. Apparently the browser just puts <html><head><body> tags around the haml code. Just noticed at the 'element' column.

Comment: @Bas van der Veen as off what I understand you have to create the haml file with the .haml ending and later on convert it into an .html file using your console and the previously mentioned command. [Here](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/haml/) is another example that might help you! Just create a .haml file and later on convert it into an .html file instead of using the .html.haml as it might try to display the content as html like you described in your answer. Hope it helps and you can solve your problem with this

Comment: It works! Found it out minutes before you sended your answer haha. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy to hear that !
Happy coding ^^